# Maximum Power Transfer in a Signal Chain

Tags: analog, impedance

I have a source signal generator with source resistance Rs, I want to buffer/amplify the signal before using it further. Do I need to match the input impedance of the amplifier to the source resistance as to maximize the power transferred or do I need to maximize the input impedance to have no voltage drop across the source resistance?

Comment: It depends on rise time/prop delay for match impedances too and low Q ringing.  Otherwise a low Z voltage source is just double the matched Z voltage. The grid is not matched to load so it can give good load regulation error. But an RF is matched to prevent frequency dependent return loss. If slew rate is high, watch out for C. You can boost. 10MHz clock into high Z but reactive loads may slow th edges.

Comment: So in short, it depends on specs for dynamic load error V and ringing specs then power transfer efficiency . ok?